# google's API .NET SpreadSheet Connection

Tags: .net, google-sheets

Here's my problem, I'm trying to do some stuff with my Google's SpreadSheet. But I don't understand what "exampleCo-exampleApp-1" could be and where's to find that information on my Google Documents account.

```
SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
```

What I understand from that applicationName, is that it begins with the "Compagny" name followed by "Application" Name and finish with a version of some kind?

---- Follow-up ----
I think that the "exampleCo-exampleApp-1" is just a name, the name of the application that I'm writing (need confirmation)...

The real problem is that each time that I make a command that needs to be connected to the server it fails...

The stack pile looks like that:

(when I do: service.Query(query); )

```
at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
at Google.Gdata.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
System.Exception: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.):SendFailure
System.Exception: the authentication or decryption has failed.
System.Exception: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
```

(when I do: service.QueryClientLoginToken(); )

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at Google.GData.Client.Utilities.QueryClientLoginToken(Google.Gdata.Client.GDataCredentials gc, System.String serviceName, System.String applicationName, Boolean fUseKeepAlive, System.Uri clientLoginHandler)
System.Exception: The authentication or decryption has failed.
System.Exception: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: oxffffffff800b010a
```

Here's my test code:

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {           
        SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("testAppName");
        service.setUserCredentials("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxx");

        string token = service.QueryClientLoginToken();
        Console.WriteLine("token = {0}", token);

        SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

        Console.WriteLine ("The spreadsheets List:");
        foreach(SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("entry: " + entry.Title.Text);
        }

        Console.WriteLine ("The End!");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this has something to with [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/detail?id=427)

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 11.10 and fixed it by typing `mozroots --import --sync` in the users shell to update the used server certificates.